# Displaying same data once in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table named files with the following values

> File Name   | End User Name
> file1              |            CNS
> file2              |            CNS
> file3              |            CNS
> file4              |            EndUser2

As you can see, the end user name is same. So what I want to do is basically display the end user name once and add a button that shows the list of all the files containing the end user name "CNS". I want "CNS" to display once only, being a column of "files" table.

> End User Name | Files
> CNS                             | View Files
> EndUser2               | View Files

I'm confused about what query will I use to display the same end user names only once.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. I doubt that the sample is properly representative of the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As every entry in that table is accessing files, you don't need to fetch anything with `file` and you don't need to group anything:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT user,
'View Files'
FROM tbl;
```

Comment: Ah, okay, seems I misunderstood :-) The button is not ment to be labeled with the file names, but the file list is shown on button click. Haha. You are right, a simple distinct query does the job to get the users of course.

Comment: You should use standard single quotes for string literals, though.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes it seems a rather simple task, not sure if there are other things (not File related) in his table. Thanks for the hint with the single quotes!

Answer (score 2):

You want to aggregate your rows to get one result row per end user, so `GROUP BY` end user. You want the filenames belonging to a user. You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get a string of the file names.

```
select 
  end_user_name,
  group_concat(file_name order by file_name) as files
from mytable
group by end_user_name
order by end_user_name;
```